# use QueryString with asp:MenuItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, menuitem

How do I pass a string with QueryString from a MenuItem?
I tried

`/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=<%(String)Session["sessUserName"]%>"`

But this returned errors..

Is there a way to do this within the menuitem, or do I have to do it in the OnClick event?

As per requests, more code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    onmenuitemclick="NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick">
        <Items>
              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UserManagement/UserManagement.aspx" Text="User Management">
                   <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UserManagement/UserManagement.aspx" Text="Manage Users" />
                   <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx" Text="New User"/>
              </asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=<%(String)Session["sessUserName"]%>" Text="FYI Access Request"/>
        </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: **Parse error**
`Literal content ('<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItemCollection'.`

Comment: Post more code please, you're doing something wrong here..

Comment: Thats it.. I have a button on my Master, than when clicked I want to pass the session variable to the page.  There is no other code involved.

Comment: @Matt There must be more stuff on that aspx page than that. Could you post that please?

Comment: Done.. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl='~/UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=<%=(String)Session["sessUserName"]%>' Text="FYI Access Request"/>
```

I haven't worked with WebForms as much lately, but I think you need to use the `<%= %>` tag (as opposed to `<% %>`). I also recall some issues where using single quotes (`'`) instead of double-quotes fixed something, but that may or may not be an issue here.

#### Edit

It sounds like you may need to take care of this in the code-behind:

```
public void MyAccountLinkInit(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ((MenuItem)sender).NavigateUrl = 
        "~/UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=" + Session["sessUserName"];
}
```

... and wire up this handler like this:

```
<asp:MenuItem OnInit="MyAccountLinkInit" Text="FYI Access Request" />
```

Comment: I'm not getting the Parse error any more, however this method is just returning the literal string.. not passing the variable.. 
url becomes  ...UserManagement/UserDisplay.aspx?UserName=<%=(String)Session["sessUserName"]%>

Comment: @Matt: You'll probably have to create an OnInit handler that sets the NavigateUrl instead of doing it inline in the .ascx file, then.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function GoToPage(url) {
         window.location = url + '?ins=<%=cid %>';
         return false;
     }

 </script>
<asp:MenuItem Text="FINANCIAL SUMMARY" NavigateUrl="javascript:GoToPage('ClientMainView.aspx');"/>
```

Comment: Is there some benefit of this pattern over the answer that was already accepted?  The additional JavaScript seems unnecessary, when the `<%=(String)Session["sessUserName"]%>` can be injected directly into the `NavigateUrl` attribute as per the accepted answer.  And what is `cid`?